# how to access a node when path contains space using node.xpath?

Tags: xpath, marklogic

I need to use `node.xpath` to access a JSON node, but the property name contains space, like "First Name":

```
empDesc = cts.doc('/employee/employee1.json').xpath('//First Name');
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
empDesc = cts.doc('/employee/employee1.json').xpath('//*[name(.)="First Name"]')
```

But you are probably better off converting this to a JSON object and using normal access methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `node()` with an argument inside MarkLogic XPath:

```
empDesc = cts.doc('/employee/employee1.json').xpath('//node("First Name")');
```

If you need to grab multiple properties, you could also convert to a JSON object first, and access that the regular way, like Mary suggested. Something like this:

```
let doc = cts.doc('/employee/employee1.json').toObject();
let empDesc = doc.employee['First Name'] + ' ' + doc.employee['Last Name'];
```

HTH!